# Counting dictionary items in a column

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

I have a dictionary

```
billable =  {'nonop'   : [99221, 99234, 99238, 99252, 99253, 99254, 99255, 99282, 99283, 99284, 99285, 99239, 99222, 99223, 99218, 99219, 99220, 99217, 99235],
             'rounding'   : [99231, 99232 ,99233, 99225, 99226],
             'clinic' : [99243, 99211 ,99215, 99213, 99214, 99212 ,99205, 99203, 99204, 99202, 9924, 99244, 99245, 99024],
             'critcare' : [99292, 99291]}
```

and a df with a column CPT, df['CPT'] with a list of many entries, dtype: object, approximately 4000 rows

I am trying to output the total count of each dictionary item

non-op = 1400 (sum of all the nonop dictionary items above)
rounding = 500 (sum of all the rounding dictionary items above)

etc.

I tried this with a limited list.

```
nonop = ['99212', '99234']

df2 = pd.Series([df['CPT'].str.count(c).sum() for c in nonop], index=nonop)
print(df2)
```

But it just returned

99212    0.0
99234    0.0
dtype: float64

From the excel file itself I know there are 25 instances of 99212 in the column

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Can you please share (part of) your data or is it private?

Comment: cpt_data = {
    'CPT:' [99212, 99212, 99203, 99205, 99226, 99234, 99545, 99212, 99002]
}
df = pd.DataFrame(cpt_data)

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, this is one way about it

```
# list of the values
noop=[99221, 99234]

# using loc, filter CPT id preset in the list, and take value count
df.loc[df['CPT'].isin(noop)]['CPT'] .value_counts()
```

```
99234    1
Name: CPT, dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to do it.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(cpt_data)
df['label'] = df['CPT']

for cat in list(billable.keys()):
    df['label'] = np.where(df['CPT'].isin(billable[cat]), cat, df['label'])
```

Output:

```
    CPT          label
0   99231     rounding
1   99232     rounding
2   99243       clinic
3   99221        nonop
4   99211       clinic
```

You can find the total values in each category using `value_counts`method

```
df['label'].value_counts()
```

Output:

```
           label
clinic         2
rounding       2
nonop          1
```

Answer (score 0):

Given the data you added as a comment, you can do two things.

Use value_counts for each category.

```
df['CPT'].apply(lambda x: next(iter([key for key, value in billable.items() if x in value]), np.NAN)).value_counts()
```

What would be better is to transform your billable dictionary into a dict where each number is mapped to the correct category.

```
mapping = {code: category for category, codelist in billable.items() for code in codelist}
```

giving you:

```
{99221: 'nonop', 99234: 'nonop', 99238: 'nonop', 99252: 'nonop', 99253: 'nonop', 99254: 'nonop', 99255: 'nonop', 99282: 'nonop', 99283: 'nonop', 99284: 'nonop', 99285: 'nonop', 99239: 'nonop', 99222: 'nonop', 99223: 'nonop', 99218: 'nonop', 99219: 'nonop', 99220: 'nonop', 99217: 'nonop', 99235: 'nonop', 99231: 'rounding', 99232: 'rounding', 99233: 'rounding', 99225: 'rounding', 99226: 'rounding', 99243: 'clinic', 99211: 'clinic', 99215: 'clinic', 99213: 'clinic', 99214: 'clinic', 99212: 'clinic', 99205: 'clinic', 99203: 'clinic', 99204: 'clinic', 99202: 'clinic', 9924: 'clinic', 99244: 'clinic', 99245: 'clinic', 99024: 'clinic', 99292: 'critcare', 99291: 'critcare'}
```

You can then use:

```
df['CPT'].map(mapping).value_counts()
```